# Windows Phone run code when app is resumed

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro

I'm looking for a way to track when my Windows Phone app is "resumed", its properly an event (I know that on Android this is done with the onResume method).

My app is a Windows Phone 8.0 project and is using the Caliburn Micro framework 1.5.2.

I've searched google and found out that Windows Phone uses something called tombstoning, correct? But i've not been able to implement it to my app, because of lacking knowledge about the subject. I've not found any tutorials on how to do this in the Caliburn Micro framework.

So my question is this: How do you implement a "resume" feature that works like Androids onResume?

Any help is much appreciated.

Solution: Since my Caliburn Micro bootstrapper was setup as it should be i was able to use the following method in my ViewModel:

```
protected override void OnActivate()
    {
        base.OnActivate();
    }
```

This works like Androids onResume. And was just what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

reference the `StorageHandler<YourViewModel>` with respect to handling storing any data associated with the present screen. There are limitations with the storagehandler and complex types

Note: Anything that uses this method of "tombstoning" will need to be in the container as a singleton. `container.Singleton<YourViewModel>()`.  While the OnActivated / OnDeactivated overrides are present in each viewmodel if inheriting Screen or IViewAware, then you would have to write your own storage mechanism. The StorageHandler<> is built in and is sensitive to the navigation state.

Of course there is some configuration of the StorageHandler<> with respect to properties you want to store.

http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/windows-phone  look for the Tombstoning header.

Answer (score 0):

In your `App.xaml`, define handlers as follows:

```
<Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
  <shell:PhoneApplicationService
      Launching="Application_Launching"
      Closing="Application_Closing"
      Activated="Application_Activated"
      Deactivated="Application_Deactivated"/>
</Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
```

- `Launching` is called when your app first starts up
- `Closing` is called when your app is closing
- `Activated` is called when your app becomes active after being deactivated (not called when the app starts up)
- `Deactivated` is called when your app is sent to background (not called when the app is closing).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking into a feature explained in the below link :

[Fast App Resume For WP8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj735579(v=vs.105).aspx)

Activation Policy should be set to Resume in the manifest file.

```
<DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="MainPage.xaml" ActivationPolicy="Resume"/>
```

Comment: The OP asks for the method for resuming event in Caliburn Micro